# ¿Es posible redireccionar a una acción dentro del constructor de un Controller usando ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un `Controller` llamado `GlobalController` , todos los `Controllers` van a heredar de él, y su objetivo es validar si el usuario ya está autenticado, entonces, declarando el constructor del `GlobalController` de esta forma:

```
public class GlobalController : Controller
{
    IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    public GlobalController()
    {
        if (!Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
}
```

¿Es posible que si un usuario no está autenticado, me redireccione al `LoginController`?

Así como está mi código me envía el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error 2   Since
>   'Web.Project.Controllers.GlobalController.GlobalController()' returns
>   void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Lo cual es lógico porque no se espera un valor de retorno, si le quito el `return` para que la instrucción quede de esta forma `RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");` es como si no realizara ninguna acción, no genera error y la ejecución del código continúa.

Nota: Utilizo **MVC 5** y **Owin Authentication**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La solución consiste en crear un `FilterAttribute`, de esta forma se puede validar si el usuario está autenticado en el sitio, y en caso de que no hay iniciado sesión realizará una redirección al Login:

Código del `FilterAttribute`:

```
public class ValidateAuthenticationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" }));
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Código del `Controller`:

```
[ValidateAuthenticationFilter]
public class GlobalController : Controller
{
    //To Do
}
```

Así, todos los `Controllers` que hereden de `GlobalController` pasaran por el `ValidateAuthenticationFilterAttribute` para validar la sesión.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba utilizando esto:

```
[Authorize]
public class GlobalController : Controller
{

}
```

El atributo `Authorize` verifica si te autenticaste al sitio, si no lo hiciste te redirecciona a la la página de Login.

Comment: Probé agregando el atributo `[Autorize]` y funciona (*thumbs up +10*), sin embargo, como requiero realizar diferentes validaciones es por eso que opté por una solución más personalizada. Publiqué la respuesta de lo que realmente requería.