# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: c#, mvc

tengo una situación, espero me puedan ayudar. 
Estoy teniendo un error de ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS cuando desde el BaseController de una aplicación MVC 4.5 intento redireccionar al usuario que no esta logueado a la pagina de Login. Cabe mencionar, que esta pagina esta también configurada como pagina de inicio.

Codigo de pagina de inicio:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cuenta", action = "IniciarSesion", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Código en el base controller que redirecciona a la pagina de login en caso de no esta autenticado:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Cuenta", action = "IniciarSesion" }));
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Con este código estoy recibiendo el error mencionado anteriormente. Si me pueden ayudar les estaré agradecido. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de tu `CuentaController`?

Comment: Actualmente no estoy en un Pc, sin embargo supongo que quieres saber si hereda de BaseController y si así es. El tema es que si no hereda como sabrá que el usuario está logueado cuando entre a la aplicación y se le re dirija al login?. O tendría que hacerlo heredar de otra clase con un comportamiento menos genérico?

Comment: `CuentaController` es el único Controller que no debe heredar del filtro `BaseController`, cualquier otro Controlador que tengas sí. Esto es debido que donde se hace el login es indiferente que haga o no la validación del filtro. Por [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45059/es-posible-redireccionar-a-una-acci%C3%B3n-dentro-del-constructor-de-un-controller-u) tengo una respuesta que habla justamente de lo mismo ;)

Comment: Excelente amigazo... muchas gracias!.